# Retrieving Google Chrome web search history

Tags: google-chrome

How can I retrieve web search history on Google Chrome? My history data gets cleaned after 10 weeks. Is it possible to view the files? If so, how do I access them?

Answer (score 4):

[This page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/465?hl=en) explains the specific steps based on device.  In general, go to the [Web & App Activity](https://history.google.com/history/) page (accessed securely via your account) to view your history.  From there, you can view your web search history.

There's also "History" via the drop-down menu to view browser history, but it shows more than just search history.

Comment: The first part of your answer seems to be talking about ***Google*** search history.  The second part may be able to give you some information about your web searching history in *the current profile of* the current browser.  While these have some overlap, they are not the same thing.  I don't know for sure which one the OP is interested in, but note that he *says* "web searching history on Google Chrome".  I would guess that he already knows about browser history.  In any case, what is your solution to the problem of being unable to look back more than ten weeks?

Comment: @G-Man: I don't know if there is a way to view search history for any other search engine.  [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/364470/is-there-a-way-to-view-google-chrome-browsing-history-past-three-months-ago) addresses the 10-week problem, suggesting that history past that cannot be viewed through standard means.