# My history in Google Chrome only goes back about 3 weeks. I need to go back further. How?

Tags: history

My History in Google Chrome now only goes back about 18 days and I need to go back further.  How do I do this?

Comment: At this point, you can't. You needed to expand the history before.

Comment: I have been able to go further back in the past.  And: how does one 'expand' the history?

Comment: @RonMaupin means you have to configure Chrome to remember a history period longer than 3 weeks and then, in the future you'll be able to retrieve items from earlier dates. Extending the configured history-save time does not cause Chrome to "remember" what it had forgotten, it just allows it to remember what it knows now for longer.

Comment: Hmm, a simple Google search reveals this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/364470/is-there-a-way-to-view-google-chrome-browsing-history-past-three-months-ago and there is NOT a way to configure Google to remember for longer periods of time. But, that references 3 months, not 18 days.